# Prevent Uploadify from asynchronously uploading multiple files

Tags: uploadify

Is it possible to prevent uploadify from uploading multiple files asynchronously? Ideally, I would like it to have auto set to true, and it works from the first file to the last one by one.

I am running into an issue where I am storing files in the Sitecore media library and it is creating duplicate paths to the files instead of putting both the files under one path.

I've tried adding `'async': false` to the config I pass into the call to uploadify, but no dice there (didn't expect that to work).

I've look on the uploadify forum and there doesn't appear to be an answer there. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So although I could not find a way to make it not upload asynchronously, I did find that you can limit the number of files uploadify can upload simultaneously using this setting: simUploadLimit. So all I did was set that to one, and that resolved my issue.